# Prevent customer portal users from owning cases?

Tags: case, queue, ownership, service

In our org we only want our support agents owning cases. There have been mistakes where people have set customers to be the owners of cases, which causes problems. I'm trying to find a way to prevent this. I was thinking about doing some sort of thing where

```
IF Case Owner's Account != (Our Org's Account), move to X Queue
```

The problem with that is that any Queue (i.e. our Help Desk Queue) doesn't have any sort of thing like an Account associated with it, so that kind of trigger wouldn't work. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: how this case is getting created?

Comment: Check if the owner is a user. If so see if the user has a contactid. If so block it

Comment: @SantanuBoral Email2Case